# Syntax error in setting up Stripe payment processing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an "unexpected tASSOC" syntax error with the last line of this code in my application layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", &crarr; :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
```

The error is encountered right before `STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY`:

```
unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
```

This code matches the [RailsCast Stripe tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast) as far as I can tell, but the tutorial is from 2011 and may be outdated. I know the hashrocket syntax is old, but I wouldn't expect that to cause the error.

Comment: What is that `&crarr;` doing in there? Some sort of copy'n'paste thing?

Comment: It appears that way in the tutorial as well, but you're right -- I don't really know why it would need to be there. When I removed it I moved on to an Uninitialized Constant error, which makes sense as I haven't finished the tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste error in the RailsCast code, Bates isn't paying attention to his work it seems :)

Comment: Heh. All the more reason to learn how all of this stuff works myself, so I can write my own stuff instead of typing along like a faithful little monkey. (And then scratching my head like one, too.)

Comment: Typing things out is usually better than copying/pasting if you are trying to learn something. If you had typed that out to begin with, you probably would've stopped to think about what that `&crarr;` was doing there.

Comment: Thanks, regulatethis -- I do type everything, and when I hit `&crarr;`, I looked it up, but the definition I found didn't shed much light. I made the classic mistake of shrugging and moving on ... and we all know that never ends well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a random carriage return in the tutorial code.